# An elementary but formal proof that the Moebius strip is not orientable

Tags: surfaces, orientation, mobius-band

We define surfaces as images of $C^1$ functions from $K \subset\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, with $K$ compact, and we say a surface is orientable is we can pick **continuously** a normal vector in each point. We don't have the tools of differential geometry.

Is there an elementary proof that the Moebius strip is not orientable? I'm looking for one that doesn't use a lot of...technology...maybe using path connectedness?

Thanks!

Comment: One explicit way is to write down a parametrization of the Möbius strip and  calculate the unit normal as you go around it.

Comment: I'd have to show the two possible initial elections and prove that the y determine the function, I suppose...

Comment: You may find it in Montiel and Ros Curves and surfaces